# How can I view all values that my update query has changed? in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, inner-join

Hey guys i have a new problem with my sql...

i try to update all articles that are assigned to a certain category in my shopware shop.

i built a query for it:

```
update s_articles_prices
INNER JOIN s_articles on s_articles_prices.articleID=s_articles.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_supplier on s_articles.supplierID=s_articles_supplier.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_details on s_articles.id=s_articles_details.articleID
SET price = price + 10
WHERE s_articles_supplier.name="category name"
```

now i would like to know, which values my query has updated...

I have a select query too, can i connect these two querys to show exactly that tables they i have ben updatded with my update query?

Here is my select:

```
SELECT s_articles.id as aid, s_articles.name as aName, s_articles.supplierID as sID, s_articles_prices.pricegroup as pricegroup, s_articles_prices.price as price, s_articles_supplier.name as sName, s_articles_details.ordernumber as sku
FROM s_articles
INNER JOIN s_articles_prices on s_articles.id=s_articles_prices.articleID
INNER JOIN s_articles_supplier on s_articles.supplierID=s_articles_supplier.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_details on s_articles.id=s_articles_details.articleID
WHERE s_articles_supplier.name="category name"
```

I would like to have a similar output as the select now, so that i can check at a glance if my update has worked

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: as MySQL does not allow  `WITH updated_records AS ( UPDATE ... ) SELECT FROM updated_records`  like PostgreSQL does there is no other way knowing the only option is writting triggers.

Comment: @RaymondNijland would it be possible with a select query and update subquerys?

Comment: To know what you are updating try to do the update query with the condition ex:
`
YOUR UPDATE QUERY
WHERE id IN (Here your select query) 
`
But also try to use the mysql function `mysql_affected_rows()` maybe it can help!

Comment: O i forgot about using a temporary table.. You can make a "snapshot" before the update then you can join to know the difference and only select those changed records.. But it will consume resources which can be alot when the temporary table need to be written to disk

Comment: @DiarSelimi thank you for the hint, but i want to try to solve it without php.. :D and the WHERE .. IN variant don´t work, but i want to see this function again :) thx

Comment: @RaymondNijland i have solve my problem with the CREATE TEMPORARY .. command, i hope that my update query is correct, but at least i have a nice output :)
thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of DiarSelimi and RaymondNijland I was able to solve my problem.

I have now done it this way:

I have create a sql script with this parts:

create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE snapTable 
SELECT s_articles.id as aid, s_articles.name as aName, s_articles.supplierID as sID, s_articles_prices.pricegroup as pricegroup, s_articles_prices.price as price, s_articles_supplier.name as sName, s_articles_details.ordernumber as sku
FROM s_articles
INNER JOIN s_articles_prices on s_articles.id=s_articles_prices.articleID
INNER JOIN s_articles_supplier on s_articles.supplierID=s_articles_supplier.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_details on s_articles.id=s_articles_details.articleID
WHERE s_articles_supplier.name="category name";
```

run my update:

```
update s_articles_prices 
INNER JOIN s_articles on s_articles_prices.articleID=s_articles.id 
INNER JOIN s_articles_supplier on s_articles.supplierID=s_articles_supplier.id 
INNER JOIN s_articles_details on s_articles.id=s_articles_details.articleID 
SET price = price + 10 
WHERE s_articles_supplier.name="category name";
```

and compare my temp table with the live table:

```
SELECT aid, sku, snapTable.price, s_articles_prices.price as newPrice 
FROM snapTable
INNER JOIN s_articles on snapTable.aid=s_articles.id
INNER JOIN s_articles_prices on snapTable.aid=s_articles_prices.articleID;
```

and you'll have something like that:

```
aid|sku     |price            |newPrice
-------------------------------------------------
2  |number  |202.60504201681  |212.60504201681
2  |number  |202.60504201681  |212.26050420167996
```

maybe it will help someone else too :)